# Problem with two normal maps on different UV's

Tags: uv

I tried to combine two normal maps - each with it's own UV map.

But I noticed the problem. When I rotate an UV island on the first UV - it is shaded as it should. But when I am rotating an UV island on the second UV, it breaks normals.

I noticed that normals are working only for active layer. It looks like it is shading the second normal map the same way it shades the first one, even though the second one is rotated. Thank you!

[image: Correct normals]

[image: Incorrect shading (shadows on different sides)]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what was the problem. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I did not set the UV map on "Normal Map" node. When I set it to correct UV map, everything works. Also... even if I do this - it only displays correct UVs when not in Edit Mode, so if someone have this issue, be aware of that.